# Node.JS and synchronous database queries

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a node.js application I need to do something like this: (pseudocode, of course)

```
if(loadedData is empty){
    loadDatafromDatabase <<---- this one is async
}
useLoadedData
```

Of course, loading data from database is an async process, so useLoadedData tries to use data BEFORE the loading is complete.
Is there any clean way to wait for loadDataFromDatabase to return its results, before going on?

I've seen many people mentioning callbacks as a correct solution, so I was tempted to do something like:

```
if(loadedData is empty){
    loadDataFromDatabase( callback useLoadedData )
}else{
    useLoadedData
}
```

but it looks quite dirty to me. Any better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems fine to me. Just define `useLoadedData()` once elsewhere and call it/pass it as a callback in your code as many times as you want

Comment: That only looks "dirty" if you're not used to looking at async/callback code. It's the async version of `if(loadedData is empty) {loadData; useData;} else{useData;}`

Comment: I'm not very used to writing async code :) I guess tweaking the program flow to adapt to situations like this one is not considered bad practice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with including node-fibers, you can try wait.for

https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

```
var wait=require('wait.for');

function process(){
   if(!data){
       data = wait.for(loadDatafromDatabase); 
       // loadDatafromDatabase is *standard* async
       // wait.for will pause the fiber until callback
   }
   useLoadedData(data);
}

wait.launchFiber(process);
```

Comment: Interesting idea! Did not know about wait.for, thanks! If I understand correctly, this "simulates" sequential programming without completely blocking node's event loop, right?

Comment: Yes, it allows you to call async functions and "wait" for the callback. It's like async/await, without the explicit "async". Any standard async function is "awaitable" with no changes required.

Answer (score 0):

The node way of doing this would be something like this:

```
db.query(queryString, callbackproc);

function callbackproc(resultSet) {
  // do both cases here
}
```

Comment: On the second pass, the data is already there and I don't need to execute the query again, so I can't rely entirely on the post-query callback to compute my data.